# Windows std::fstream modify file after open()?

Tags: c++, windows, file

I'm a bit confused about this working on Windows with standard c++ lib.

Having this code:

```
std::fstream _fs;
_fs.open('file.txt', std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::ios_base::ate);
```

and file.txt:

```
abcdefg
SUB
```

Being 'SUB' hex value 0x1A

After the open(), without any write() or close(), I found that file.txt is modified. I found this debugging the code and stopping it after the open().

file.txt is modified (modify date in file also) without the SUB value, I mean, the file.txt is now:

```
abcdefg
```

Is this correct? or am I doing something wrong with open() modes?

Hope anybody can point me on this.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you check the file content? What if your run the same without `std::ios_base::ate` flag?

Comment: Hi, I check the file with UltraEdit, I have the file opened there and it alerts me when the file changed and ask if I want to reload it. I found that if I remove the std::fstream::out flag, the file remain unmodified, removing std::ios_base::ate flag also modified the file.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default. In this case, that means changing `std::fstream _fs; _fs.open('file.txt', std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::ios_base::ate);` to `std::fstream _fs('file.txt', std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::ios_base::ate);`.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks for the tip, I'll keep this in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because MS-DOS used that character as an end-of-stream marker, and Windows has some special handling for it in text mode.

The Windows [documentation for `fopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019) (which using `fstream` eventually boils down to) says

> In text mode, CTRL+Z is interpreted as an EOF character on input. In
>   files that are opened for reading/writing by using "a+", fopen checks
>   for a CTRL+Z at the end of the file and removes it, if it is possible.
>   This is done because using fseek and ftell to move within a file that
>   ends with CTRL+Z may cause fseek to behave incorrectly near the end of
>   the file.

and Ctrl+Z is the SUB character.

Comment: Nice! I did not read that doc, never though that OS could make that kind of change in a file. Thanks for clarify!

Comment: @webbi I had no idea about this either, but got curious and started looking for an explanation. Thanks for discovering this quirk and asking.